# what does initLoader do if loader already exists?

Tags: android

On developers.android.com it says, 
"Ensures a loader is initialized and active. If the loader doesn't already exist, one is created and (if the activity/fragment is currently started) starts the loader. Otherwise the last created loader is re-used."

So what does it mean by last created loader is re-used? **Which method does it immediately call after initLoader()  if the loader already exists?**

I am asking this because I am still not sure how caching works with Loaders.

```
 protected void onCreate(Bundle savedInstanceState) {
    super.onCreate(savedInstanceState);
    setContentView(R.layout.activity_main);

    getSupportLoaderManager().initLoader(loaderId, null, MainActivity.this);
}

public Loader<String[]> onCreateLoader(int id, final Bundle loaderArgs) {

    return new AsyncTaskLoader<String[]>(this) {

        String[] mCachedData = null;

        @Override
        protected void onStartLoading() {
            if (mCachedData != null) {
                deliverResult(mCachedData);
            } else {
                forceLoad();
            }
        }

 . . . . .

}
```

In the above code, if the loader already exists then what is the flow? What method does it call it next after initLoader. Because if it calls onCreateLoader then my cached Data is initialized to null again.

Comment: If the Loader exists then you will just need to wait for `onLoadFinished` to be called.

Comment: Oh. Thanks alot. I understand now!

Answer (score 0):

If you check the LoaderManager source [initLoader](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/LoaderManager.java#608) creates loader only if a loader with the same id doesn't exist.

> Which method does it immediately call after initLoader() if the loader
>   already exists?

It tells the loader to call `onLoadFinish` only if the loader is already done with its job (Check [this](https://android.googlesource.com/platform/frameworks/base/+/refs/heads/master/core/java/android/app/LoaderManager.java#628)).
If the loader has not completed its job, the loader itself will call the `onLoadFinish` after it has finished with it.